# Docker Error UnixODBC - [01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager] Can't open lib 'XY' : file not found

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile, hana, unixodbc

i am trying to install a driver from UnixODBC in docker to be able to connect to HANA Express from R.

Locally on my mac it is sufficient if I use

1. install unixodbc via homebrew
2. install odbc package via install.packages("odbc") in an R terminal
3. download the SAP HANA client and reference the .dylib file in the odbcinst.ini config file as follows:

> [HDBODBC]
> Description = HANA ODBC driver
> Driver = /Applications/sap/hdbclient/libodbcHDB.dylib

I try to download exactly the same in my dockerfile without the SAP HANA client, because I copy the "libodbcHDB.dylib" file directly into it. My Dockerfile looks like this:

> #Use Python 3.10 as the base image
> FROM python:3.10
>
> #Set non-interactive installation to avoid prompts
> ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
>
> #Update and install dependencies required for R and other tools
> RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y 
> software-properties-common 
> apt-transport-https 
> wget 
> curl 
> libcurl4-openssl-dev 
> libssl-dev 
> libxml2-dev 
> libpq-dev 
> libnode-dev 
> libmpfr-dev
>
> #Add CRAN repository to get the specific R version
> RUN wget -qO- https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/marutter_pubkey.asc | tee -a /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cran_ubuntu_key.asc
> RUN add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-cran40/"
>
> #Install R and verify the version
> RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y r-base r-base-dev && R --version
>
> #Install odbc driver
> RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
>
> #Install specific R packages
> RUN R -e "install.packages(c('causaleffect', 'dagitty', 'RPostgreSQL', 'igraph'), dependencies=TRUE, repos='https://cran.r-project.org/', lib='/usr/lib/R/site-library')" > install_log.txt 2>&1
>
> #Install sepecific R packages which require specific versions
> RUN R -e "install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/bnlearn/bnlearn_4.9.tar.gz', repos=NULL, type='source', lib='/usr/lib/R/site-library')"
> RUN R -e "install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/jsonlite/jsonlite_1.8.7.tar.gz', repos=NULL, type='source', lib='/usr/lib/R/site-library')"
> RUN R -e "install.packages('https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/data.table/data.table_1.14.8.tar.gz', repos=NULL, type='source', lib='/usr/lib/R/site-library')"
> RUN R -e "install.packages(c('odbc'), dependencies=TRUE, repos='https://cran.r-project.org/', lib='/usr/lib/R/site-library')" > odbc_r_package_log.txt 2>&1
>
> ENV R_HOME /usr/lib/R/
>
> #Set the working directory for the application
> WORKDIR /app
>
> #Copy the Python requirements file and install Python dependencies
> COPY requirements.txt /app/
> RUN pip install --upgrade pip
> RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
>
> #Copy the rest of the application's code
> COPY . /app
>
> #Set driver for HANA in odbcinst.ini
> RUN echo "[HDBODBC]\nDescription = HANA ODBC Treiber\nDriver = /usr/lib/libodbcHDB.dylib" > /etc/odbcinst.ini
>
> #Reset the non-interactive frontend
> ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=

When I then start the container and a method is called in R that tries to establish a test connection via the odbc r package, I keep getting the following error message, even though the file is located at this path:

[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/libodbcHDB.dylib' : file not found

i am trying to install a driver from UnixODBC in docker to be able to connect to HANA Express from R and expected to get a connection to hana express in r within docker